# In what order are keys inserted into a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
>>> stuff = {'age': 23, 'name': 'ZaneTribal', 'height': 74}
>>> print stuff
{'age': 23, 'name': 'ZaneTribal', 'height': 74}
>>> stuff['born in'] = 'Montreal'
>>> print stuff
{'age': 23, 'born in': 'Montreal', 'name': 'ZaneTribal', 'height': 74}
>>> stuff['children'] = 'Nope'
>>> stuff
{'age': 23, 'born in': 'Montreal', 'children': 'Nope', 'name': 'ZaneTribal', 'height': 74}
>>> stuff['zoo'] = 'WTF'
>>> stuff
{'name': 'ZaneTribal', 'age': 23, 'zoo': 'WTF', 'born in': 'Montreal', 'height': 74, 'children': 'Nope'}
```

When adding to dicts, how does Python decide where to place new keys? The order is clearly not alphabetical, nor by type.

Comment: It is best to think of a dictionary as an unordered set of key: value pairs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dictionaries are unordered. The order they come out in when you print them depends on internal details of the implementation.

If you need to retain order, use `collections.OrderedDict`.

Answer (score 2):

The order is undefined.  Python can put the keys in whatever order it wants, and this order can change between Python versions.  You should not rely on the order of dict keys.

Answer (score 1):

dict in python is actually hash table.

therefore, it's meaningless to track where python put the keys, since things after hashed should be considered random.

when you use keys() to extract every key, you should not make any assumption about order too.